# Are any of the objectives in Wrath of the Righteous time sensitive based on the in-universe clock?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

I've recently picked up Pathfinder: Wrath of the Righteous, and I'm quite liking it so far. However, I am concerned that at one point I'm going to encounter the major problem I felt all the time in Kingmaker, namely that the game will give me deadlines that are time based, rather than milestone based. Not finishing certain parts or properly preparing before an arbitrary in-universe time has passed (time that includes wasted travel time) in that game would bring certain consequences, severely impacting the difficulty of the game. I had to stop playing the game partway through act 2 because I really do not like it when games restrict my options through timers in this manner. Looming specters of imminent deadlines in games really don't work with me, and they make me either stop playing or attempt to find mods that disable them or make them inconsequential, especially when so much of the in-universe time is wasted with what's effectively a loading screen with attitude.

I have noticed that in WotR, there are some quests marked "you need to finish these within this chapter or they will fail", which I'm fine with because I have control over when I trigger these milestones. But I don't think I have encountered restrictions like above where not finishing certain parts before an arbitrary number of in-universe hours have passed either fails those parts, blocks off other content for the rest of the playthrough or makes subsequent parts of the game significantly harder. However, I may just not have encountered them. I know that in Kingmaker, many of these timed events are from the Kingdom Management aspect, which doesn't activate until Act 2.

Are there any quests or other parts of the game that have a predefined deadline based on the in-universe passage of time (rather than milestones that I can choose to trigger at my own pace) which will fail the quest or change other parts of the game if not met?

Comment: I thought about including this in my answer, but pulled it out, because it's a bit adjacent, but for what it's worth, you might want to give Kingmaker another look. The way that games timers are set up, you have ~180 days to complete a mission that takes ~14 in game days, and the rest of that 180 day period is less of a "deadline" and more of a "this is how much free time you have now before the next major quest starts."

Answer (score 3):

In Chapter One, there's a major event in which the primary base out of which you're operating in is attacked by demons. This attack occurs the first time that you rest at the base after **Three Days** have passed since you first arrive there, after leaving the caves. Once this event triggers, you'll miss out on two (well, kind of three, but one is just a talking sword) companions if you didn't already recruit them by this point, and be locked in to a few quest outcomes that aren't particularly game breaking, but I suppose count as 'meaningful'. You can avoid this by simply not resting at the tavern after 3 days have passed, until you've

> 1) Made sure to recruit Ember and Woljif
>  2) Resolve the conflict between Hulrun and Ramien, if you intend to do so nonviolently. If you want to, or are okay with killing one or the other, this can be handled after the defense event.
>  3) Visit Blackwing Library.

There are a few other impacts, but they firmly fall into the "this is different, not worse or better."

After Chapter One, the only major impact of the calendar on the overall game is the so-called "Secret Ending", which requires that you meet a variety of fairly strict conditions, up to and including, entering the final dungeon during a specific week on the calendar. Even hitting that milestone isn't particularly hard - I had to do literally months of "Skip Day" in crusade mode while watching my armies Morale tank to get it - but it does constitute "time sensitive" so, there's that.